# SignalR not loaded on bundling the js

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, bundling-and-minification

I have been using `Bundling and Minification` concept in my asp.net application. i have following code in `global.asax`

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.Add(new System.Web.Optimization.ScriptBundle("~/bundle/js")
                      .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js", 
                               "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.js",
                               "~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js"));
        System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.Add(new System.Web.Optimization.ScriptBundle("~/bundle/js1")
                     .Include("~/Content/Scripts/VerbaTrack.js",
                              "~/Content/Scripts/Helper.js"));
        System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.Add(new System.Web.Optimization.StyleBundle("~/bundle/css")
             .Include("~/Content/Css/Demo.css",
                      "~/Content/Css/Styles.css"));
    }
```

and i am referencing these files in `master page` in following manner

```
<head runat="server">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="Content/Images/VerbaTrack.ico"/>
<title>

</title>    
<asp:placeholder runat="server">  
     <%= System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/bundle/js") %>
     <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=drawing,places"></script>    
     <%= System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/bundle/js1") %>
     <%= System.Web.Optimization.Styles.Render("~/bundle/css") %>   
     <script src="signalr/hubs"></script>               
</asp:placeholder>
```

As you can see i am referencing `signalr/hubs` right after referencing `jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js`

But still it is throwing following error

`Error: SignalR: SignalR is not loaded. Please ensure jquery.signalR-x.js is referenced before ~/signalr/hubs.`

Why so ?

Comment: Are the other JS files being loaded like the jQuery and jQueryUI JS files? But only the SignalR JS file is not loading? Did you inspected this by viewing the page source?

Answer (score 1):

If the scripts are not loading the right order (please inspect the page source) you can use this to make sure the order is as provided in the bundles:

```
/// <summary>
/// Respect the order of the scripts added
/// </summary>
public class NonOrderingBundleOrderer : IBundleOrderer
{
    public IEnumerable<BundleFile> OrderFiles(BundleContext context, IEnumerable<BundleFile> files)
    {
        return files;
    }
}
```

Then assign the bundles to a variable like:

```
var scripts = new ScriptBundle("~/bundle/js")
        .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js")
        .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.js")
        .Include("/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js");
```

Then attach the `NonOrderingBundleOrderer`and add the bundle to the bundle collection:

```
scripts.Orderer = new NonOrderingBundleOrderer();
BundleTable.Bundles.Add(scripts);
```